# Change button tint color of MFMailcomposer in UIActivityController

Tags: iphone, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uinavigationitem, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have tried all possible suggestion of changing tint color of cancel button in mfmailcomposer using in UIActivity controller, no one suggestion work for me in ios 8, so please anybody have idea about how to do that ?

```
 [picker.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [picker.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Try this way [mailViewController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

Comment: Where are you setting this? May another method later alters these values with internal methods.